# MATLAB pair mapping

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to map (x,y) values to certain numbers. The situation can be explained by example like:

```
x=[-3 -1 3 1 3 1 1];
y=[-1 -3 1 3 1 3 1];

(-3,3)  => 1
(-3,1)  => 2
(-3,-1) => 3
(-3,-3) => 4 ... There are 16 values like this and I know them.
```

So, I want to get a vector which has all mapping values.

How can I implement this in MATLAB in an easier way?

My solution for this problem is as follows:

```
r_1(r_1 >2)            = 4;
r_1(r_1 <=2& r_1>0)    = 3;
r_1(r_1 <=0& r_1>-2)   = 2;
r_1(r_1 <=-2)          = 1;

r_2(r_2>2)               = 1;
r_2(r_2 <=2 & r_2 >0)    = 2;
r_2(r_2 <=0 & r_2 >-2)   = 3;
r_2(r_2 <=-2)            = 4;

consellations = reshape(1:16,4,4);
ml_container = zeros(length(r_1),1);
for a = 1:length(r_1)
    ml_container(a) = consellations(r_2(a),r_1(a));
end
```

Is there a better way for getting rid of "for"?

r1 corresponds to x

r2 corresponds to y

Comment: are there any patterns to your mapping process? i.e. x(1) map to y(1) and y(2) or something?

Comment: I described my mapping in question as (-3,3)=1... e.g
x(1)=-3 and y(1)=1 in question, I want to map (-3,1) to 1

Comment: it is not clear how this mapping works, is it based on a formula? I cannot see the pattern here. Are the values in the parentheses (x,y)?

Comment: If there is a method or pattern to the mapping, then it can be automated, if you are just choosing random values, then it might be easier if you just do something like [-3,3,1; .... -3,-3-4] and index the vector (:,3) as your result vector. (:,1:2) as your reference points

Comment: Look at `unique`, especially second argument of `unique` if you just want to map distinct pairs to distinct values. As the question stands, its extremely unclear. If the mapping vector is `z`, then `z=f(x,y)`. You have not specified any rules governing `f`, that's why the question is unclear. For example, why can't `(-3,-1)` be mapped to `1`?

Comment: The thing I want is to find a methode which does not use for.

Comment: but if only you know them, how could you use for? There must be some patterns in there? unique of y and unique of x? or something?

Comment: I can see the pattern and it can easily be done using a `for` loop but you say you do not want to use `for`, which I honestly do not understand. You want to automate something you have hard coded but you want to avoid a loop? Is the current way better then a `for` loop would be?

Comment: I realized that my way is not correct because some changes in vector affect the rest of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like 16-ary QAM demodulation, no?  I would use `histc` to separate the analog values from the I and Q (r1 and r2) channels into their bins, then use simple multiplication to assemble those into a single symbol.

```
[n r_1]=histc(x, [-Inf -2 0 2 Inf]);
[n r_2]=histc(y, [-Inf -2 0 2 Inf]);
% r_1 and r_2 now contain the bin index in their dimensions
symbol = (r_1-1)*4 + (r_2-1);  % 0-based symbol index
```

The mapping of r_1 and r_2 bins to a symbol value is arbitrary.  If you want to match whatever you currently generate, you may need to transform r_1 or r_2, for example with `4-r_1` to "invert" the mapping.  I would also generalize this by pulling 4 out into a parameter.

Comment: Is it possible to use gray with your algorithm?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  What does "use gray" mean?

Comment: I try to say gray coding

Comment: You have indices for the bins in both x and y dimensions, and a combined symbol index (0-15) assigned in column-major order.  You can map these symbols to any other symbols with a simple look-up table.